# Precedence of rules for Gmail

Tags: gmail

Gmail rules can be configured to:

1. Sort and place messages in a folder
2. Forward messages to other email accounts

Account #1 forwards inbound mail to Account #2.  The goal is to change inbound messages to:

1. Sort any messages from bob@mail.com to a folder named bob
2. Forward all other messages to account #2

Is this possible?  If so, any example or guidance is appreciated.